# Char pointer dereference

Tags: c, dereference

I try to change uppercase to lowercase in the sentence represented by `char *`.
I get an error: access violation when I make pointer dereference.

```
// Uppercase to lowercase
char *str = "My sentence";
*str = 'm';
```

Comment: why don't you tag a language?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you have used the wrong format to define a string.  You want:

```
 char str[] = "My Sentence";
 *str = 'm';
```

What you have written defines a pointer and then assigns "My Sentence" to the *pointer* as a memory address.  You are receiving an access violation because you do not own the memory at "My Sente" which is most likely the address being referenced.

Answer (score 1):

The code `"My sentence"` is a "string literal" and the system intentionally places string literals in memory that is marked read only, to help catch bugs. In C, it is undefined behaviour to change the bytes in a string literal (even though the characters do not have a `const` qualifier!), while in C++ the characters are `const` and you may not edit constant memory. The nice side of these rules is that if you have the same string twice in a program, they can be deduplicated and only one copy is kept.

You may instead wish to allocate some fresh memory and edit your string there. @David Hoelzer's answer shows how to place a copy on stack memory. Here is how one could do it on the heap:

```
char *str = calloc(200, 1);
strcpy(str, "My sentence");
*str = 'm';
/* ... */
free(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is [undefined behavior](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) `6.4.5p6  String literals,  page 63` to mutate such a string literal:

> .... If the  program  attempts  to  modify  such  an  array, the  behavior  is
> undefined.

Instead of mutating the address of a string literal (the address is pointed by `ptr`), you can use a string literal to initialize an array.

On the page 130 of the ISO9899 you see so:

> The declaration

```
 char s[] = "abc", t[3] = "abc";
```

> defines  ‘‘plain’’ char array  objects s and t whose  elements  are  initialized  with  character  string  literals.
> This declaration is identical to

```
char s[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' },
t[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
```

> The contents of the arrays are modifiable. On the other hand, the declaration

```
char *p = "abc";
```

> defines p with  type  ‘‘pointer  to char’’  and  initializes  it  to  point  to  an  object  with  type  ‘‘array  of char’’
> with length 4 whose elements are initialized with a character string literal. ***If an attempt is made to use p to
> modify the contents of the array, the behavior is undefined.***